# Runing a docker container with the --privileged option

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently trying to figure out how to run a container on Elastic Beanstalk with the privileged mode. I read the documentation, but i can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're launching to Docker running in ECS.

ECS using task definitions to define how a docker container should start up. Specifically, the task definition property: [`privileged`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_security) is what you're looking for.

ElasticBeanstalk uses the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file to generate a task definition. According to the [documentation for v2 of the file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_v2config.html#create_deploy_docker_v2config_dockerrun_format), you can add this flag to one of the objects in the containerDefinitions block.

So, something like this should work

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "my-app",
      "image": "some:app",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "privileged": true,
    }
  ]
}
```